# Android Facebook SDK openActiveSession(…) fails

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk, autologin

I'm having the following issue when calling

```
public static Session openActiveSession(Activity activity, boolean allowLoginUI,
            StatusCallback callback);
```

of Android's Facebook SDK. I'm currently using `allowLoginUI = false` as I know that the user is currently logged in and I want to get the session from Facebook.

I can't reproduce it locally but apparently (according to tracking data) this method is failing to open the session on 99% of the times. What i wanted to know is why could this fail if the Facebook session has not expired. According to the docs

```
If allowedLoginUI is false, this will only create the active session and open
it if it requires no user interaction (i.e. the token cache is available and
there are cached tokens)
```

but I'm having trouble figuring out what this means.
I know that it may be the case that the user has disable my app from setting, but I find it hard to believe that almost everyone its doing that.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post more code? Or, for example, how are you determining that the user is currently logged in?

Comment: I would like to, but i'm afraid i can't. Besides its quite a lot of code, as we support different types of login. In the case of Facebook, I use `Session.isOpened()` to determine whether the user is logged in or not (and then request/check publish permissions). I understand that without the code, help can be quite limited but anything will be welcome =)